# gcloud Data store Key to use UUID

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-datastore, uuid, datastore

I am new with **gcloud DataStore Key.** I was wondering how I can define my Key to use UUID ?

For example in the Instrument.java class below, how to make sure the Key object use UUID ?

```
import java.util.Objects;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Key;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.mapping.Entity;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
public class Instrument {
    @Id
    Key instrumentId;

    private String type;

    public Instrument(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying it right.

As defined in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#kinds_and_identifiers),  `A data class must have one and only one field dedicated to storing the primary key of the corresponding datastore entity.` So, the key is the UUID of the Datastore Entity.

In this case, since you are using the Spring framework `org.springframework.cloud.gcp`, to define the which attribute is the key, you have to specify it in the way specified in the [Datastore Spring framework documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/multi/multi__spring_data_cloud_datastore.html#_keys) is to use `@Id`.

```
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.mapping.Entity;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
public class Singer {

    @Id
    String singerId;

    String name;

}
```